# Angular 8 Drop down selected item not showing on page load

Tags: angular, select, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I'm using this code:

```
<select id="lessorSelect_{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="item.tempId" name="lessorSelect_{{i}}" class="edit">
       <option *ngFor="let lease of Account.detailLeases" 
           [attr.selected]="lease.rendition_detail_id == item.id ? true : null"
           [ngValue]="lease.tempId">
           {{lease.name}}
       </option>
</select>
```

[image]

As showing in the attached picture selected item was not showing.

[image]

Comment: You're binding the selected value of the select to `item.tempId` and trying to set the selected property of the option to `item.id`. Firstly, these 2 approaches find against each other - just let `[(ngModel)]` do the work. Secondly, which one out of `tempId / id` should it be?!

Comment: Thanks, I solved this by replacing item.tempId.